# Different output for boost sha1 and openssl library for same input

Tags: c++, boost, openssl

I was trying to learn more about boost and sha1. I have written below code to test the output. Apart from boost, i have installed openssl library also.

I have written below code and i am getting different values for same value in openssl and boost sha1.

**inpur string : "te99999"**

```
std::string makeSHA1boostV1(const char text[])
    {
        boost::uuids::detail::sha1 sha1;
        unsigned int hash[5];
        sha1.process_bytes(text, sizeof(text)-1);
        sha1.get_digest(hash);
         std::ostringstream buf;
        std::cout << "Hash: ";
        for(std::size_t i=0; i<sizeof(hash)/sizeof(hash[0]); ++i) {
            std::cout <<"sha hash "<<hash[i]<<std::endl;
            std::cout << std::hex <<hash[i];
            buf << std::hex <<hash[i];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sha1  "<<buf.str()<<std::endl;
        return buf.str();
    }
```

**Boost output**:
Hash: 
sha hash 83008267

sha hex  4f29b0b

sha hash d107070c

sha hex  d107070c

sha hash 753cedeb

sha hex  753cedeb

sha hash 2adb54bf

sha hex  2adb54bf

sha hash 6c0fdc93

sha hex  6c0fdc93


**sha1**  4f29b0bd107070c753cedeb2adb54bf6c0fdc93

We can also check the output of sha1 using openssl library also using below command.

**command** echo -n "te99999" | openssl sha1

**openssl output**:: (stdin)= 04f29b0bd107070c753cedeb2adb54bf6c0fdc93

Here leading **zero** is missing in boost sha1.
I am not able to understand why **0** is missing.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with boost, but a problem of your use of streams.

Printing numbers with `<<` will, by default, discard leading zeros. if you don't want that you need to specify that:

```
buf << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(hash[i])*2) << hash[i];
```

and equivalently for `std::cout`.

---

Additionally you are using pointers wrong. `text` is a pointer to `const char`. Therefore `sizeof(text)` is the size of the pointer type, not the size of the array that `text` points to. It happened to work in the example in the question, because the length of your input string (including null-terminator) happened to be `8`, which is the size of a pointer on 64bit systems.

You can obtain the length of a C style null-terminated string with `std::strlen`. (requires `#include<cstring>`)

Or, much better, take a `const std::string&` instead of `const char*` as `text` parameter. It offers `.size()` and `.c_str()` methods to get the string length (without null-terminator) and a pointer to a null-terminated C style string.

---

Also: using something that is specified in a `detail` namespace is usually not a good idea. `detail` usually means that the things it contains are implementation details not intended to be used by the library user.

Comment: not getting expected output after setting std::setfill('0') .

Comment: @RAW In what way are you not getting the expected output? Did you also set `std::setw`?

Comment: buf << std::hex <<std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(hash[i])/2) <<hash[i];

Comment: Still not getting leading zeros

Comment: @RAW `std::setw(sizeof(hash[i])/2)` should be `std::setw(sizeof(hash[i])*2)`. I fixed that mistake in my answer some hours ago. (`*2` because each byte requires two characters to be represented in hexadecimal).

Comment: Using Boost for input string "te27" it shows sha1 " 0362a21f893e4844196e1e9ec6ec354fb28b622e" and for same input openssl gives output as "54c7bde40499807c12659a871970ca60e5e98d17". Both as showing different output. I am not sure using setfill and setw are giving correct output.

Comment: Already add your comment..After that i am getting output like this.

Comment: I am really sorry .. I did not read your llast part of comment..Now everything working fine.. Thank you for your help..